# firestore keep updating in infinite loop

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I just want to update the count table one time but it keeps updating in the infinite loop can someone help me with this.

```
referral_code=referral_editText.getText().toString();
db.collection(REFERRAL_CODE_KEY).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        assert queryDocumentSnapshots != null;
        for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshots:queryDocumentSnapshots){
            if(referral_code.equals(documentSnapshots.get(REFERRAL_CODE).toString()))
            {
                count = parseInt(String.valueOf(documentSnapshots.get(REFERRAL_COUNT)))+1;
                Map<String, Object> referralCountDocData = new HashMap<>();
                referralCountDocData.put(REFERRAL_COUNT,count);
                klog.d("### referral",count+"");
                db.collection(REFERRAL_CODE_KEY)
                        .document(documentSnapshots.getId())
                        .update(referralCountDocData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: please ask me any questions regarding this.

Comment: You need to stop/detach your listener once you update your value

Comment: how can I do that, can you please help me with that.

Comment: Because you add snapshot listener thats why its keep updating

Comment: @subratasharma you can update directly if you want it to update only one time, addSnapShotListener trigger every time there is a change in collection and that exactly in your case

Comment: how can i update directly @Asad Ali

Comment: please give me some clue @AsadAli

Comment: wait @subratasharma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204935/discussion-between-asad-ali-and-subrata-sharma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you could do something like this not everythng is perfect but it gives you a nice idea.

> oldCount-> you can read it from document.getData()

```
 var docRef = db.collection(REFERRAL_CODE_KEY).doc(referral_code);    
 docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
 @Override
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
        if (document.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            //read oldCount here from document.getData()
             Map<String, Object> docData= new HashMap<>();
             docData.put(REFERRAL_COUNT, oldcount + 1);
             docRef.set(docData)
             .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                 @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
                 }
             })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                     Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                 }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detach your listener, so that callback stop getting called.
As per official document https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener You need to use remove method to detach listener

```
Query query = db.collection("cities");
ListenerRegistration registration = query.addSnapshotListener(
        new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            // ...
        });

// ...

// Stop listening to changes
registration.remove();
```

Comment: as per your code you need to detach listener inside onEvent() method before your for loop so onEvent() will not call once again while you updating value